# Which IP Framework (If Any) to use in C# .Net 4

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

It seems that **System.net.Sockets** had some performance problems in multithreaded applications in previous versions of .Net. and that **SocketAsyncEventArgs** was (At least partially) created to address these.   However it looks like using SocketAsyncEventArgs and getting it right is a nontrivial process as shown in this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/socketasynceventargs.aspx?fid=1573061&fr=76&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick).

Ive looked at some frameworksthat might be of use http://nitoasync.codeplex.com/ & http://supersocket.codeplex.com/

If I was looking for Maximum performance in an TCP application using managed code should I write around SocketAsyncEventArgs? and run the risk of discovering performance problems in production which are impossible to replicate in testing or should I use one of  aforementioned frameworks?.

I am not working with C# that long. Most of my experience has been in C++ but I have zero experience in this area. Im using .Net 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for something free, I've had good experiences with SuperSocket.
However, if you need a bit more functionality...http://www.chilkatsoft.com/socket-dotnet.asp is really worth the extra dime.

Regular updates, and very easy to work with. Lots of examples, and thorough/good documentation for the most part (some of the functions (very few), contain a "To be documented")

The examples are really what sets them apart, imo.

Comment: Chilkat Library looks good. I have not purchased it yet as the developer did not respond to some simple questions which makes me wonder about support?